# Click on Follow Buttons in Instagram using Selenium Java

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neB6m.png)

Hi, trying to automate follow button clicks using java but having trouble using the javascriptexecutor in for loop. Here is my code:

```
     List<WebElement>clickOnFollowButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]"));
        for (int i = 0; i < clickOnFollowButton.size() ; i++) {
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]")).get(i).click();

            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickOnFollowButton);

        }
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this argument `"arguments[0].scrollIntoView();"` should be first before `.click`.

And you must make each member in the list to be a `WebElement` variable before it is executed by `JavascriptExecutor`, then click it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clickOnFollowButton.size() ; i++) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]")).get(i);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    element.click();
}
```

Btw, there is another way to do a looping list using for each, like this:

```
List<WebElement> clickOnFollowButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]"));
for(WebElement element: clickOnFollowButton) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: thank you @frianH it is working. Can you please also advise what to do to avoid clicking the same users every day and also where should I be putting the implicit wait method? Thank you so much

Comment: @serdar2225 you can put implicit wait after initialize `driver`, example : `driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;`

Comment: @serdar2225 and your question *`what to do to avoid clicking the same users every day`*, I don't understand, please more explanation.

Comment: I guess this explains better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337082/instagram-user-following-automation-project